# Python Multiprocessing Pool + Requests not terminating

Tags: python-2.7, asynchronous, python-requests

I'm having a problem trying to download files asynchronously using python requests and multiprocessing modules. Basically what I'm trying to do is download a file from one site and upload it to another for backup.

What works:

1. Running the same code only synchronously (for loop)
2. Uploading asynchronously

What doesn't work:

1. Downloading asynchronously (even if the pool size is 1)

What I see:

1. Nothing. The code runs fine until the get request is made, and it just hangs there indefinitely.

This makes me think that possibly this is some kind of conflict with streaming requests and async calls? I'm not sure if anyone else has had this issue or any insight into it. Below is a simplified version of the code:

```
def async_download(file_name):
    r = requests.get(url, params=file_name, cookies=cookies, stream=True)
    print 'this never runs'
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
            # filter out keep-alive new chunks
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)
                f.flush()
    return file_name

def finish(file_names):
    utils.deleteLocalFiles(file_names)

def main():
    p = Pool(processes=1)
    result = p.map_async(async_download, file_names, callback=finish)
    result.get()`

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: did you figure anything out for this?  i have a similar issue in my project.

Comment: @Trent Unfortunately no, I ended up having to go the synchronous route.